# Continuity of anti-derivative multivariate functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I just need some hints to solve the following problem.

Let $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be a continuous and integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Is the function

$$
g(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\,dx_{n}
$$
continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$? If it is, how can I prove that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose on $\mathbb {R}^2$ we set $f(x,y) = \exp[-|y||x|^{1/2}(1+x^2)].$ Then $f$ is continuous and integrable on $\mathbb {R}^2$ (see below), but if

$$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy,$$

then $g(0)=\infty,$ so $g$ is not continuous on $\mathbb {R}.$

(To see $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb R ^2,$ integrate first with respect to $y,$ making the change of variables $y = t/[|x|^{1/2}(1+x^2)],$ and then integrate with respect to $x.$ We are using Fubini here.)